# Ruby: Regex - How to change first digit (0-9) that comes after a [A-Z] to a *?

Tags: ruby

I was wondering how one would go about changing the first digit (0-9) that comes after a capital letter (A-Z) in a string to an asterisk WITHOUT using `sub`. You can put this in a method called `replace_digit` if you want.

Comment: What about just going through the string, character by character?

Comment: Does no `sub` mean regex's aren't actually an option?

Comment: @oldergod a regex or brute force, anyway :^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = "not here 0 but here A5 and here B7, okay?"
begin
  loop do
    a[/(?<=[A-Z])\d/] = "*"
  end
rescue IndexError
end
puts a
# not here 0 but here A* and here B*, okay?
```

No `sub` :)

**EDIT:** I just noticed "first digit" - so just remove the loop; and if you can assume there will always be a match, you can remove the exception handling too.

```
a = "not here 0 but here A5 and here B7, okay?"
a[/(?<=[A-Z])\d/] = "*"
puts a
# not here 0 but here A* and here B7, okay?
```

**EDIT2:**

this works too, without lookbehind: `a[/[A-Z](\d)/, 1] = "*"`

Comment: hi amadan. What does the `?<=` stand for in your reg ex?

Comment: @edmund: Positive lookbehind. It means: from here to the left, I want to match an uppercase letter, but I don't want it to become the content of the match. If I put regexp like this: `/[A-Z]\d/`, then both the uppercase letter and the digit would have been replaced by the asterisk. The regexp as I wrote it says, replace the digit only if preceded by a capital letter (but leave the letter out of it).

Comment: ooo I learned something. nice! But I thought when you do `a[something]`, `something` is supposed to be an index number (e.g. a[0] would equal "o"). Why is it that you can stuff in a regex in a[something]?

Comment: @Edmund: Because [Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) :p

Comment: @Edmund: Actually, this works too, without lookbehind: `a[/[A-Z](\d)/, 1] = "*"` (`1` means 1st group, i.e. just the contents of the parentheses will get replaced). Lemme edit it in...